# How to burn DVD/Blu-Ray disk with copy protection

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning, copy-protection

I've created video studying material for my students and would like to know if it's possible to burn my disks with basic copy protection. I realize that it will be possible to copy them anyway if one knows what to do but *creating basic protection against plain copying* would be great!

Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about [CSS on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System). IMO it's a joke and I would advise you not not bother with it or any other form of obnoxious DRM.

If you still want to go ahead, are you willing to pay a license fee per disc? CSS key sets are licensed by the DVD Copy Control Association to manufacturers who incorporate them into their discs ***during the pressing process***. CSS keys can only be added to discs replicated from the glass master. The keys are stored on the lead-in area of the discs, on tracks that are not even recordable on DVD-Rs/DVD+Rs. Even if they were, the firmware of normal DVD writers sold for home use is restricted from writing information to those tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you developed your own brand new format of optical drives, there are no other ways to protect your information from copying. The only one way is to make a loader for your videos which would check if password provided by user matches some schema in your loader.

Comment: I heard that disk authoring programs such as Adobe After Effect or such could do it?